# Minimal example using ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie with Flutter, starting on my learning journey a few weeks ago.

My goal is to increase my knowledge of working with the flutter [ChangeNotifier](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) so I have created a minimal example to test my knowledge:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  // runApp(const MainApp());

  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: const MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Consumer<MyModel>(
            builder: (context, model, child) => Column(
              children: [
                Text('Total price: ${model._mydata}'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    model.increment();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    model.decrement();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Minus"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _mydata = 0;

  void increment() {
    _mydata++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement() {
    _mydata--;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The application compiles and runs as expected, but I wanted to ensure my approach does not implement any anti-patterns for ChangeNotifier?

---

If you feel that my question does not meet Stackoverflow requirements, can you please let me know in the comments so that I can improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good and If you want to optimize the widget tree, wrap only the text widget with a Consumer. This way when _myData gets updated only the Text widget will rebuild.

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Consumer<MyModel>(
              builder: (context, model, child) =>
                  Text('Total price: ${model._mydata}'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<MyModel>.increment();
              },
              child: const Text("Add"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<MyModel>.decrement();
              },
              child: const Text("Minus"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```